# Why this weird results when playing around with task and continuewith

Tags: task, continuewith

```
    Dim d = 1
    Dim task1 = Task.Delay(1)
    Dim task2 = Task.Delay(2)
    Dim task4 = Sub() d += 1 'Type of task4 is delegate sub


    Dim task3 = task1.ContinueWith(task2) ' error
    Dim task5 = task1.ContinueWith(Sub() d += 1) 'works
    Dim task6 = task1.ContinueWith(task4) 'error
    Dim task7 = task1.ContinueWith(New Action(Of Task)(task2)) 'error the "new" operator lead to         Public delegate void Action<In T>(T obj); 
    'translated to vb.net it should be Public Delegate Sub Action(Of In T)(ByVal obj As T) 
    'so no new definition. Not sure what (Of In T) means
    Dim task8 = task1.ContinueWith(New Action(Of Task)(Function() task2)) ' Somehow it works. Is this even the right way to do it? Why?
```

The first 4 rows are normal. I just set things up

```
Dim d = 1
Dim task1 = Task.Delay(1)
Dim task2 = Task.Delay(2)
Dim task4 = Sub() d += 1 'Type of task4 is delegate sub
```

What I really want to do is to create another task, say task3. And task3 will simply be task1, continue with task2

I try a bunch of different things and follow from some answer to some questions (I think I made the question, but I forget where) a long time ago.

Doing it

```
Dim task3 = task1.ContinueWith(task2) ' error
```

Simply doesn't work.

Doing it

```
Dim task5 = task1.ContinueWith(Sub() d += 1) 'works
```

surprisingly work. Even though Sub() d += 1 is just a lambda sub. Now I know, delegate, lambda sub, and action is kind of synonym to one another, and to what extend I have no idea.

However, Sub() d += 1 has nothing to do with Task. ContinueWith accept Action(of Task) right?

So I have no idea. Besides, doing it like that would only work for non await function.

```
Dim task6 = task1.ContinueWith(task4) 'error
```

That one doesn't work. Even though task5 and task6 should be the same and have same type.

Usually if we have `dim someVar=5`, we can put `someVar` anywhere we put `5`. Same value, same type.

Here, we have

```
Dim task4 = Sub() d += 1
```

I can put

```
Dim task5 = task1.ContinueWith(Sub() d += 1) 'works
```

but not
Dim task6 = task1.ContinueWith(task4) 'error

Now, ContinueWith accepts Action(of Task) so a natural thing to do is to create an Action(of Task) object

```
Dim task7 = task1.ContinueWith(New Action(Of Task)(task2))
```

Doesn't work.

Then finally someone suggested using

```
    Dim task8 = task1.ContinueWith(New Action(Of Task)(Function() task2)) ' Somehow it works. Is this even the right way to do it? Why?
```

And it compiles. However, how the hell it works?

Basically I am calling the `Action(Of Task)` constructor and I am passing `Function() task2` as a parameter. Why?

Where is the constructor of Action(Of Task)? I go to definition and I see

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

Which is translateable to

```
Public Delegate Sub Action(Of In T)(ByVal obj As T)
```

And I have no idea what that means. I thought it should look like Public Sub New Action (of T)(something)

It doesn't even have New word in it.

And I am very confused.

Can anyone explain all these phenomena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates represent code that can be run in the future. Tasks represent code that is already running.

`ContinueWith` runs code in the future (when the task completes), so it only takes delegates as its arguments, not tasks.

On a side note, you should not normally use `ContinueWith`; use `Await` instead.

Comment: Someone said that. But how can I create a task whose job is to await 2 tasks

Comment: @user4951: Either use `Task.WhenAll` or write your own `Async` method that just `Await`s them.